# Prove that every group table is a Latin square

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Please Check my proof

**strong text**Suppose every group is not Latin square.
If it is ,it must exist some element appear more than one time in each row and column.
Without lose generality,I assume idenity and inverse appear more than one time for each row and column.
If it is,from defination of group,the identity and inverse are uniques It can appear one time for each row and column, that contradict assumetion.
Then every group table is Latin Square

Comment: What do you want us to do here?

Comment: You should pick an arbitrary element and not identity or inverse.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What do you mean when you write "inverse appear[s] more than one time"? "Inverse" of what?

Comment: I suppose the question is, "Is this a good proof?" If so, I think the answer is "no", though a full answer would describe all the mistakes in more detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To begin with, for a proof by contradiction, we want to begin
with the negation of the conclusion.
But "every group is not Latin square" is not the negation of
"every group table is a Latin square".
The negation is, "Some group is not a Latin square."

"Not a Latin square" does not mean "some element appears more than
one time in each row and column."
It means, "Some element appears more than one time in one row
*or* some element appears more than one time in one column."
(For a group table, the "row" statement is equivalent to the "column"
statement, but that is because it is a group table, not because it
is not a Latin square.)

Now it is true that the identity cannot appear more than once in
a row or column. That is the same thing as saying the inverse is unique:
the inverse of $x$ is found by finding the row of column $x$ in which the identity appears. So uniqueness of identity and inverse gives you
just *one* element that can't be repeated in any given column.
We need something that shows $y$ can't be repeated in column $x$,
where $y$ could be any element.

"Without loss of generality" is something you can write only when
it really does not matter which thing you choose out of all the
choices available, not when you choose something special
such as identity or inverse.